# Most popular post for last 7 days

Tags: wp-query, popular-posts

I need to change the most popular post widgets with date restrictions.

For an example, how should I get most popular posts(post_views_count) of last 7 days.

original query,

```
$popularposts = new WP_Query('showposts=10&meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&ignore_sticky_posts=1')
```

then I changed that to,

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array( array( 'after' => '-7 days' ) ),  
    'showposts' => 10,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

However it doesn't give any results. How should I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax to get posts from the last week is `1 week ago`. Just another note, `showposts` is replaced in favor of `posts_per_page`. Apart from that, your query should work.